# flutter get layout rendered event

Tags: dart, flutter

In order to scroll the ListView with the ScrollController right after it gets displayed I have to call the animateTo function with a delay because otherwise the layout is not rendered at the time when the animateTo Function is called.

Is there a way to get a layout rendered event and then call the animateTo function or some other solution besides using a Timer?

```
class MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {

      bool listViewVisible = false;
  ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      child: !listViewVisible ? null :
      new ListView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        children: <Widget>[
          //Some Items
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  //does not work
  void showAndScrollListViewWithoutTimer() {
    setState(() {
      listViewVisible = true;
    });

    _scrollController.animateTo(100.0,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        curve: Curves.easeOut);
  }

  //works
  void showAndScrollListViewWithTimer() {
    setState(() {
      listViewVisible = true;
    });

    new Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
      _scrollController.animateTo(100.0,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          curve: Curves.easeOut);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The just published package https://pub.dartlang.org/packages?q=after_layout provides a mixin for that.

It uses

```
WidgetsBinding.instance
    .addPostFrameCallback((_) => afterFirstLayout(context));
```

Comment: This is only the first layout event. If I rotate my phone, a new layout is done but this is not called.

Comment: @NephewofStackoverflow For what ??? Its setting call back function, and it should reuse that function for any change.